# how generate One hot encoding for 40x10 classes?

Tags: image, class, machine-learning, math, classification

I have 40 classes each has 10 replications, I need to generate one hot encoding as below :

class 1, replication 1:  [ 1 0 0 0 ....40(0) 1 0 0 0 0 ....0(10)]
  class 1, replication 2: [ 1 0 0 0 ....40(0)  0 1 0 0 0 ....0(10)]

I am not sure how can i code the input array : for example the code below all the classes are in one array :

```
 X = [2,1,2,3,3]'
   LinearIndices = sub2ind([length(X),3], [1:length(X)]', X); 
   tmp = zeros(length(X), 3); 
   tmp(LinearIndices) = 1
```

The above code is not working , its generate :
[ 1 00000 ...0(400)]

Comment: This question is pretty unclear, what do you mean by 40(0), 0(1), etc? How is this one hot encoding? What are you asking for?

Comment: @Cmxu, The  one hot encoding for the first class and first replication  should be: [ 1 0 0 0 ....40(0) 1 0 0 0 0 ....0(10)], how can i generate this formula using matlab ?

Comment: It might also be helpful if you could define what you mean by a replication. Do you mean that you have 10 instances of each class?

Comment: @Cmxu, Do you mean that you have 10 instances of each class?, Yes

Comment: Let me try to clarify for you in case this is helpful to others, let me know if this is right. You want an array that is length 50, it is split into an array of length 40 and an array of length 10. The array of length 40 is the one-hot encoded class. The array of length 10 is the one-hot encoded enumeration of an instance in that class.

Comment: Let me further say that this isn't how one hot encoding works traditionally in the sense that one-hot means that you have one element hot (or set to 1). Here you will have two elements set to one. I can't really think of a situation where you would need to one hot encode each instance of a class and append that to the one hot encoded class.

Answer (score 1):

Here, let me try to answer your question as I see it asked, or at least point you in a direction. As I see it, you are trying to do two seperate one-hot encodings and then concat them, so lets do it like that. There is a matlab function called `ind2vec` that will do one-hot encoding.

```
X = zeros(400,2);
X(:,1) = repelem(1:40, 10);
X(:,2) = repmat(1:10, 1,40);
encoding = [ind2vec(X(:,1)', 40)', ind2vec(X(:,2)', 10)'];
full(encoding)
```

Comment: No,  its not  working :(, No  code for replications ?

Comment: These are the replications you described. Check the first row it is [1,0,...,0,1,0,..0] where there are 39 zeros and 9 zeros, the second row is [1,0,...,0,0,1,0,...,0] where there are 40 zeros and 8 zeros. This is what you described above. Can you tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: In any case, you never explained what a replication is or why you care about it, that may help me answer your question a bit better. What you described isn't one-hot encoding.

Comment: The code work on the column 1 in which  the  one hot generated correctly, but  for the replications, its not generating ? you have used  400x2 , i think we should have 40x10 ? The example above is clear ( the out put) !!!

Comment: What, you have 40 classes and each has 10 replications. That's 400 elements. Check the size of encoding. It is 400x50. Check each row. It has two ones, the one in the first column and the one for the 'replications'

Comment: Why would it be 40 x 10? If you are asking a different question please clarify.

Comment: 40 classes x 10 replications per class = 400 total instances. I have 400 x 2 to indicate each instance, the first column is the class, the second column is the 'replication' number. I can't believe I have to type this but 40 x 10 = 400.

Comment: Look at the code. `ind2vec(X(:,1)', 40)` creates the one-hot for the classes. `ind2vec(X(:,2)', 10)` creates the one hot for the replications.